# Finite subsets and limit points in the finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology

I am reading Principles of Topology by Croom and unclear about the following example.

> Consider the topological space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}')$ where $\mathcal{T}'$ is the finite complement topology...
> A finite subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has no limit points with the respect to the finite complement topology... if $x$ does belong to $B$, then $\{x\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus B)$ is an open set containing $x$ which contains no point of $B$ different from $x$.

Why is $\{x\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus B)$ open? Specifically, since $\{x\}$ is finite, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ has a finite complement and so is open. Thus $\{x\}$ is closed. So $\{x\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus B)$ is the union of a closed set and an open set and therefore is not open.

What am I missing?

Comment: The complement of $\{x\}\cup B^c$ is a subset of finite set $B$ hence is finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
\begin{align}
\mathbb{R} \setminus \big( \{x\} \cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus B)\big) &= \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\} \cap \mathbb{R} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \setminus B)\\
&= \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x\} \cap B\\
&\subseteq B,
\end{align}
so the complement of $\{x\} \cup (\mathbb{R} \setminus B)$ is finite and hence it is open by definition of the finite complement topology.

Comment: Yes, thanks! A union of an open set and a closed set can be open of course, e.g, the union of any set with the whole space in any topology. My mistake!